# A Remark in Weibel's "Introduction to Homological Algebra"

Tags: homological-algebra, abelian-categories

In the section on the derived functors of the inverse limit(with $...3\rightarrow 2 \rightarrow 1 \rightarrow 0$ as index category), Weibel constructs the inverse limit using the map $\Delta$ in the photograph.
 Later, he remarks that everything goes through for any $AB4*$ category. But I can't even construct the map in the general case. My question is, how does one do this for any $AB4*$ category?[image][image]

Comment: The question is just about how to define $\Delta$ without elements ? This is easy then, $\Delta$ is the difference between the identity $\prod_{i\in\mathbb{N}}A_i\to\prod_{i\in\mathbb{N}}A_i$ and the map such that on the $A_j$ component, it is $\prod_{i\in\mathbb{N}}A_i\to A_{j+1}\to A_j$.

Comment: Thanks, it was so silly of me to miss that!